# Array size determination C++17

Tags: c++, c++17

I'm trying to determine the size of an array using the `std::size()` function, but my compiler brings this error:

> /root/Desktop/practise.cpp:9:34: error: ‘size’ is not a member of ‘std’; did you mean ‘size_t’?

This is the first code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int values [] {2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};

    cout <<"The array size is:"<< std::size(values);


    return 0;
}
```

Upon changing the statement `std::size(values)` to `std::size_t(values)`, a huge number that doesn't seem accurate pops up. The value outputted is:

> 140725039324624

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To use `std::size`, you need to include the `<iterator>` header.

By using `std::size_t` instead, (which is a type, and not a function), then you perform function-style casting, which returns you the memory address (pointer) of the first element of the array as an integer, hence an incoherent value to your eyes.

Comment: I once read that C-style casts are dangerous. You are basically telling compiler "I don't care about type safety, do everything to make this type another type".

Comment: @Code_Infinity • C-style casts and functional-style casts are both dangerous.  When you need to cast, use static_cast, dynamic_cast, reinterpret_cast, or const_cast.  Sometimes casting is unavoidable.  But as much as you can, try to avoid needed the cast in the first place, and don't resort to cavalier casting.